# What can cause a default route to fail?

Tags: asp.net, iis, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012

I installed a deployed and working website (Windows Server 2003, IIS 6) onto an AWS instance, however unless I append a route name, the IIS default webpage is returned. For example, www.mysite.com returns the IIS page, while www.mysite.com/Home brings up the website.

I tried adding a route:

```
 routes.MapPageRoute("/", "Home", "~/Default.aspx");
```

but it had no effect. I tried to hack around it by suffixing the URL with "Home" in Application_BeginRequest (Globals.asax.cs) and redirecting it, but 
I much prefer and would welcome a clean solution to this problem. I suspect the issue is rooted in the enhanced security of IIS 8.5, but am not expert enough to understand how and why.

**AWS Versions:**

Windows Server 2012 R2

IIS 8.5

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <defaultDocument enabled="true">
     <files>
        <add value="home.html" />
     </files>
  </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/defaultdocument

Comment: Although this looks promising, it turns out I didn't have the website correctly defined. I needed to create folder in wwwroot and add it as an application. That did the trick. i should have answered this question myself, but gave up on it days ago. Thank you for your answer, it may help in the future.